# How can I convert a repeated column element in to a title row?

Tags: excel

I have some rather ugly post-pivot data, much like the following:

| Location | Team | Staff | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North | 1 | 1100 | 55 |
| North | 2 | 2100 | 56 |
| North | 3 | 3200 | 91 |
| South | 1 | 7100 | 75 |
| South | 2 | 3100 | 16 |
| South | 3 | 9200 | 41 |
| East | 1 | 8100 | 25 |
| East | 2 | 9100 | 56 |
| East | 3 | 4200 | 31 |

My users don't like the duplication in the first column and would rather it be a header row with only one element, with the three resulting tables side-by-side. So, something like this:
[image]
with the obvious extension for East.

How can I achieve this automatically? I would do it by hand, but the real version of my table has a few hundred categories of values in the Location column.

Comment: *How can I achieve this automatically?* With VBA but try to code something. Please, notice that your question right now kinda looks like you are asking for a **full** developing.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I must admit, I was hoping for simple GUI solution or a really good keyboard shortcut.